# Parsing C Header Files

Tags: c++, c, yacc, lex

I have a C header file that I have precompiled using the `gcc -E` flag, and am now trying to parse using Lex and Yacc; however, it is getting hung up on typedef'd variables.

for example:

```
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
ULONG i = 5;
```

will throw a syntax error at the second line's ULONG.

I have tried to redefine part of the grammar (found here) http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html, specifically under `type_specifer` by replacing `TYPE_NAME` with `IDENTIFIER`, however that create multiple s/r and r/r errors that I am unable to fix.

Are there other approaches that you would recommend?
Or a different approach at precompiling all together?

Comment: You have to be able to differentiate between types/variable identifiers in the lexer. Thus as you parse the file you need to build up your type list in the parser in a way that is accessible for further processing in the lexer.

Comment: I am not what are you trying to do. In most cases, where I had to take data out of the code, I have created a special table with the data and included it into the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you link too:
http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html,

look at the bottom:
You will see this function

```
int check_type(void)
{
 /*
  * pseudo code --- this is what it should check
  *
  * if (yytext == type_name)
  *     return TYPE_NAME;
  *
  * return IDENTIFIER;
  */

/*
 *  it actually will only return IDENTIFIER
 */

    return IDENTIFIER;
}
```

You actually need to write the code that identifies weather a sequence (yytest, yytext+yylength] is an identifier or a TYPE_NAME. This means in the parser you need to build some structure as you parse the code so that this function can look up the identifier in the structure.

Pre-populate the structure with the default types char/int/short/long/float/double etc. The other types you will need to add as you parse the input.

Comment: Lex and yacc communicate back and forth during runtime? I assumed that lex token-ized everything before yacc did anything.

Comment: No. Yacc calls lex and gets one token at a time.